# MVVMCross Location Plugin background mode iOS9

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MVVMCross Location plugin and it's works fine on android and iOS 8 in background mode. But iOS 9 has new feature: `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates`. So, location plugin doesn't works corectly in background mode on iOS 9. Is there are any way to fix this? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** it's works fine on iOS 9 iPhoneSimulator, but not on real iPhone

Comment: Maybe you need to add something to your LinkerPleaseInclude if this is not working on a real phone?

Comment: @Martijn00 What I need to add to my LinkerPleaseInclude.cs? Sorry, I'm new to mvvmcross.

Comment: This is a general Xamarin thing: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/
An example for MvvmCross is: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/nuspec/iOSContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp